# Is this thread safe on a 32 bit system?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

My understanding of C# leads me to believe that the following is always thread safe:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static long Bar(long y)
    {
        long z = y;
        return z;
    }
}
```

However, I'm being told that because a long is bigger than what a 32 bit processor can handle in one operation that this is not thread safe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code shown doesn't ever involve memory (or any other resources) being accessed from multiple threads, nor does the method shown even allow for the *possibility* of any shared memory.  As such, any discussion of thread safety is moot.

Comment: I'm asking if there is there 'any way' you could use this method that would be unsafe.

Comment: @BVernon If you did, it would be because of a bug in that code, not because of any sort of problem with this method.

Comment: Never mind my last comment, I misread your answer the first time. Thanks! :)